# Firebase Remote message returns null data on remotemessage.getDate()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Using FirebaseMessagingService to send Remote Message Using PHP.
It was working fine till date, suddenly app stops receiving notification, after debug i found that

```
onMessegeReceived(remoteMessage)
remoteMessage.getData() returns null Array Map.
```

But I can see the payload data in Bundle

```
Bundle[{google.delivered_priority=high, google.sent_time=1556008551748, google.ttl=2419200, google.original_priority=high, 
from=982221224130, 
google.message_id=0:1556008551825452%903f05e2903f05e2, 
gcm.notification.data={"image":"https:url","nId":1313,"time":"14:05:51","priority":"normal","title":"testttt","message":"","type":"1"}, google.c.a.e=1, collapse_key=com.sam.grapemundo}]
```

I expect the result remoteMessage.getData() returns

```
data={"image":"https:url","nId":1313,"time":"14:05:51","priority":"normal","title":"testttt","message":"","type":"1"}, google.c.a.e=1, collapse_key=com.sam.grapemundo}]
```

Answer (score 0):

**First of all you have to check notification is fired or not:-**

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() == null)
            return;
        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            handleNotification(remoteMessage, remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        }
```

Comment: I am sending notification using data payload, so  remoteMessage.getNotification() is alwasys null

Comment: remoteMessage.getFrom() returns 982221224130 
remoteMessage.getMessageId also returns message_id value

Comment: String image = remoteMessage.getData().get("image"); get like this.

Comment: @swapnilmdkapse...google.c.a.e=1, is maybe creating the problem check it.